# Need someone to explain the SharedPreferences class

Tags: java, android

Android provides the `SharedPreferences` class, and we need to create an XML file to store the value of each Preferences (that is what I know). But I don't know, after using SharedPreferences.Editor to modify value, where the modified values are stored? I can't see any change in the XML file.

Also, what are the differences between `apply()` and `commit()`, `getSharedPrefences` and `getPreferences`?

Answer (score 0):

Preferences will be stored in internal memory (phone memory).

- [`apply()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#apply%28%29)
- [`commit()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#commit%28%29)
- [`getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getSharedPreferences%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)
- another [`getSharedPreferences()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceManager.html#getSharedPreferences%28%29)

I'm sorry I don't know which one is `getPreferences()` you mentioned.

Comment: there is a SharedPreferences getPreferences(int mode) method in Android. same to getSharedPreferences() but only Activity can use it, not other component

Answer (score 0):

`commit()` returns a boolean value. If the data is save then it returns `true` otherwise `false`.

If you don't care about this (boolean value) then use the `apply()` method.

`getPreferences`:
               Use this when you only need one preference

`getSharedPreferences`: Use this if you need multiple preferences in a single file